# Issue on Referencing $(this) to Multi Inputs on Submit Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple Validation Function for validating User inputs at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/35djwp3f/).
now my problem is using the `$(this).` to reference for each of the inputs which has same type. For example at this example I tried the

```
$('#email1').parent().after('<div class="err" role="alert">Can Not be Empty</div>');
```

which works but when I use the

```
 $(this).parent().after('<div class="err" role="alert">Can Not be Empty</div>');
```

I am not getting any thing for validation

Here is the code which I have

```
<div class="form-group">
    E-Mail 1:  <input type="email" name="email1" id="email1"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    E-Mail 2:  <input type="email" name="email2" id="email2" />
</div>
<button type="button" id="exe">Validate</button>

<script>
$(function() {

function emailInput(inputData) {
      inputData = $.trim($(inputData).val());
      if (inputData == "") {
          $(this).parent().after('<div class="err" role="alert">Can Not be Empty</div>');
      } else {
          return inputData;
      }
  }

 $("#exe").on("click",function(){
   $(".err").hide();
   if (emailInput($('#email1').val())){
           alert($('#email1').val());
   }   

 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: because it's a function not assigned to an event of an element, so basically there's not "this" element, try passing the desired element in the arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what I explained in the comments: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/35djwp3f/2/)**

```
$(function() {

function emailInput(elem) {
      inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
      if (inputData == "") {
          elem.parent().after('<div class="err" role="alert">Can Not be Empty</div>');
      } else {
          return inputData;
      }
  }

 $("#exe").on("click",function(){
   $(".err").hide();
   if (emailInput($('#email1'))){
           alert($('#email1').val());
   }   

 });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Amin but the Demo is not functioning correctly! as when the input is filled but still getting Error Message for Empty input.

Comment: This is because of the line `inputData = $.trim($(inputData).val());`. It is actually calling `.val()` twice, which is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Terry, Amin and Rob.

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery` provides context to it's methods (i.e. what the value of `this` is), your function does not have `this` provided so `this` refers to `window` or the global scope. If you want to use `this` and have it refer to the current DOM node, you have to call your function using the `call`,`apply` or `bind` methods and provide the value of `this` as jQuery does.

```
// first argument is the context, i.e. what this refers to, subsequent arguments are your function arguments
emailInput.call($('#email1').get(0), $('#email1').val())
```

Here are some links to explain `call`, `apply` and `bind`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is that in your emailInput function there is no reference for `this` that is why your code is breaking at this point.

this works when an element is hit with an event and you bind it to the event handler. Only this element can be used with the **this** reference., for rest elements like parents children you need to use ids or any other selector. I hope this make it clear what you are doing wrong.